# Post deleted after migration didn't result in migration rejection

Tags: support, migration, deleted-questions

I have an example on ruSO.meta, but logic seems would be same on any SE site.

The [question](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/12421/revisions) was posted on [ruSO.meta](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/) and migrated later to the main site. After that, the question was deleted by author and hence not visible in the list of questions on main site. But the migration wasn't rejected: that question is still visible (marked as "migrated") on Meta, and continues to redirect to the deleted main site question.

> [image: migrated]

Users without access to moderator tools (10k rep) will see the original post title on Meta site, but trying to look inside will redirect them to page 404 (question was removed by post author).

Is it desired behavior for migrated and later deleted question?

Comment: Was the question on the main site closed as a duplicate before it was deleted?

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog according to [timeline](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1501457/timeline) it wasn't closed before deletion. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaocP.png).

Comment: What happened on meta? Was that one closed?

Comment: @Laurel closed as "not suitable for that site" and migrated to main site (as an atomic action I think) by moderator.

Comment: TL;DR: no bug. As far as I know, the migration stub stands on its own, unless the migration is rejected, it would stick for two months on the source site then vanish. The status of the question on the target site has no effect on it, unless it's closed with reason which isn't duplicate, then migration is rejected. Since I'm not 100% sure I'm correct, only a comment.

Comment: A while ago, an override was implemented in which questions migrated from a main site to its meta would not be rejected upon non-duplicate closure. The official statement only mentioned this one direction and never mentioned rejection upon deletion. It's possible that the override occurs in both directions and all rejections, which contradicts the official statement.